# Push key value pair to map object javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following object

```
     {
     "timetable": {
         "MONDAY": {
             "start-end0": {},
             "start-end1": {},
             "start-end2": {},
             "start-end3": {},
             "start-end4": {}
         }
     }
```

i need to add `"start-end5"` to `MONDAY`. I tried to use dot operator to monday like `timetable.monday.start-end5={}` it says monday undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more completely viable (and very readable) syntax I'd like to add, just for fun:

```
time["timetable"]["MONDAY"]["start-end5"] = {};
```

Answer (score 8):

- `monday` is not `MONDAY`
- Since `start-end4` is not a valid identifier, `obj.timetable.MONDAY.start-end5 = {}` will not compile; you need to use the bracket syntax.

Thus,

```
obj.timetable.MONDAY["start-end5"] = {};
```

Comment: how can i add dynamically `start-end5 start-end6...` to my map??Is that possible?

Comment: @masSdev, what do you mean by dynamically? in iteration?

Comment: yes using iteration like `obj.timetable.MONDAY["start-end"+count]`

Comment: @masSdev, you can pass your value in the square brackets in your iteration. I think it should work.

Comment: @masSdev: What do you mean, "like `obj.timetable.MONDAY["start-end"+count]`"? That's exactly what would work, so... not sure what kind of answer you're expecting. However, unless the format is set by someone beyond your control, that's a bad way to do things; a better would be for to have `obj.timetable.MONDAY.startEnd` as an array of objects, so you'd access each using `obj.timetable.MONDAY.startEnd[5]`. You can create it e.g. using `Array.apply(null, {length: 5}).map(i => ({}))` (in ES6).

Comment: i am using angular js i have `$scope.timetable` object and `$scope.weekdays` array which contain all the days in a week  is this the way to do it  `for(var i=1;i<Object.keys($scope.timetable).length;i++)        $scope.timetable.$scope.weekdays[i]['start-end'+i]={};`

Comment: That doesn't look right, but I am not sure what you want to achieve so can't give you a better answer. Do you mean you want to reset any existing start-ends on `$scope.timetable[day]` for each `day` in `$scope.weekdays` to an empty object? That would require two loops.

Answer (score 3):

Variable name should be followed this restrictions

- Blanks & Commas are not allowed.
- No Special Symbols other than underscore(_) are allowed.
- First Character should be alphabet or Underscore.

Try like this

```
var time = {
  "timetable": {
    "MONDAY": {
      "start-end0": {},
      "start-end1": {},
      "start-end2": {},
      "start-end3": {},
      "start-end4": {}
    }
  }
}

time.timetable.MONDAY["start-end5"] = {}
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/v81vgkpn/)**</kbd>

Addtion:

how can i add dynamically start-end5 start-end6... to my map??Is that possible?

Ans

Add a loop and concat string according to value.

Like this

```
var time = {
  "timetable": {
    "MONDAY": {
      "start-end0": {},
      "start-end1": {},
      "start-end2": {},
      "start-end3": {},
      "start-end4": {}
    }
  }
}
for(var i=0;i<5;i++) // set the limit of loop according to your need
  time.timetable.MONDAY["start-end"+i] = {}
```

<kbd>[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/v81vgkpn/2/)</kbd>

Comment: well, that's the most basic restrictions @Rayon

Comment: how can i add dynamically `start-end5 start-end6...` to my map??Is that possible?

Comment: I have added my ans @masSdev

Comment: its giving monday as undefined

Comment: check demo i have attached @masSdev

Comment: i am using angular js i have `$scope.timetable` object and `$scope.weekdays` array which contain all the days in a week  is this the way to do it  `for(var i=1;i<Object.keys($scope.timetable).length;i++)        $scope.timetable.$scope.weekdays[i]['start-end'+i]={};`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125060/discussion-between-massdev-and-anik-islam-abhi).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `[""]` notation here, as your key name is not camelCase or other valid object key naming

```
a.timetable.MONDAY["start-end5"] = {};
```